# angularjs, spring boot, apache poi, can't generate excel document

Tags: angularjs, excel, spring, apache-poi

I'm trying to generate a Excel document. I'm using Apache POI version 3.14

My controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/excel")
public class ExcelRest {

    @Autowired
    private ProfilDao profilDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get",  method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getExcel(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{


        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=testExcel.xls");
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");

        // I get a List of Profil.
        List<Profil> profils = profilDao.findAll();

        return new ModelAndView(new ExcelProfilsBuilder(), "profils", profils);

    }
}
```

My ModelView :

```
public class ExcelProfilsBuilder extends AbstractXlsView {

    @Override
    protected void buildExcelDocument(
        Map<String, Object> model, 
        Workbook workbook, 
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        // On récupère les profiles provenant de la méthode REST 
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Profil> profiles = (List<Profil>) model.get("profils");

        // create a new Excel sheet
        HSSFSheet sheet = (HSSFSheet) workbook.createSheet("Profiles");
        sheet.setDefaultColumnWidth(30);

        // create style for header cells
        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        Font font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setFontName("Arial");
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.BLUE.index);
        style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        font.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        font.setColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index);
        style.setFont(font);

        // create header row
        HSSFRow header = sheet.createRow(0);

        header.createCell(0).setCellValue("Nom");
        header.getCell(0).setCellStyle(style);

        header.createCell(1).setCellValue("Prénom");
        header.getCell(1).setCellStyle(style);

        // create data rows
        int rowCount = 1;

        for (Profil profil : profiles) {
            HSSFRow aRow = sheet.createRow(rowCount++);
            aRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(profil.getName());
            aRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(profil.getFirstname());
        }

    }

}
```

To finish, I get it with AngularJs :

```
$http.get('/excel/get').then(
    function(response){

        var blob = new Blob([response], {type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"});
        var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.open(objectUrl);

    }, 
    function(response){

        //error case

    }
);
```

I don't know why, but when I receive my files, its name is, for exemple "8a4c6f51-3323-4f1b-bc4b-bd041801e66c.xls"

and I have only one cells : [Object object]

Edit : Another method which is doesn't works :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get/excel", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void getExcel(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{

    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=monFichier.xls");

    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Utilisateurs");
    HSSFRow user = sheet.createRow(0);
    HSSFCell name = user.createCell(0);
    name.setCellValue("Test");

    try {
        workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }


}
```

Edit 2 : It's working if I'm using $http.post instead of $http.get :

```
    $http.post('/list/profil/get/excel',null, {responseType:'arraybuffer'})
      .success(function (response) {
          console.log("plop");
           var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});
           var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
           window.open(fileURL);
    });
```

But I already have a bad filename.

Comment: Please specify the exact problem.

Comment: The issues are : 1) I precise a filename, but I receive a file with a very strange name. 2) I have 3 lines in my List<Profil>, but I receive a file with juste one cells which contains "[Object object]".
I forgot to specify that i'm using Spring Security, perhaps it is a problem?

Answer (score 1):

instead of

`return new ModelAndView(new ExcelProfilsBuilder(), "profils", profils);`

return like this...

```
return new ModelAndView("excelProfilsBuilder", "profils", profils);
```

**Resource Bundles:**

Create views.properties file under the applications class-path. In eclipse it is located under /src/main/resources/views.properties. "**excelProfilsBuilder**" is the view name used in excel **controller** new ModelAndView("excelProfilsBuilder", "employees",employees);

In **views.properties file**, add this entry...

```
excelProfilsBuilder.(class)=com.abc.def.ExcelProfilsBuilder
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't works. First, if I change to **return new ModelAndView("ExcelProfilsBuilder", "profils", profils);**, I don't know why, I receive 404 not found for my REST service O_O.
Then, with my line **return new ModelAndView(new ExcelProfilsBuilder(), "profils", profils);**, I enter correctly into my AbstractXlsView... I don't understand. Moreover, I can notice that response.data in my chrome developper tools is odd. I don't know if it is normal.

Comment: please check "e"  in excelProfilsBuilder, There was a typo in my answer and i corrected now..Value in properties file and in new ModelAndView should match.

Comment: Always the same problems with change 'E' to 'e'. I edit my post to show an other methods which doesn't works. So I thinks this is not due to ModelAndView.

Comment: Now, it's working with $http.post, but I always have a bad filename.